# Export association rules to PMML in KNIME

Tags: pmml, knime, market-basket-analysis

I have built an Asscociation Rule Analysis in KNIME and now I want to export those rules to PMML for further usage outside of KNIME.

Is it possible to export association rules to PMML in KNIME?

Any help would be great!

Comment: No, I think that is not possible with KNIME yet. At least not easily. You can create the PMML's XML as a String after you have merged the output table to a single row using a Java Snippet, convert that String to XML, that XML to PMML and use PMML Writer to save as a PMML.

Comment: If you can build your model in R, it's easy to export it as PMML. Just an alternative!